# Using USB-C port replicator hub with USB-A laptop and desktop

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-2

So, I've just bought a Lenovo USB-C hub (port replicator) which I want to use with my laptop and desktop computers. However, neither of my devices has USB-C ports and I can only use USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 ports with an adapter.

The hub in question is: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07FQD4KMV

The adapter in question is: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01J16IOIS

Turns out that my initially planned setup doesn't work. I'm not sure why but my guess is that the conversion of USB-C to USB-A renders the hub undetectable for Windows 10.

I had concerns whether either the hub or adapter are not functioning properly but after tests with other devices I concluded the problem is with the USB ports on the laptop and desktop.

Do you have any ideas how I can bypass this issue? I am thinking as last resort I may have to buy and install PCI Express USB-C adapter card on the desktop but I am clueless on what to do with the laptop.

Comment: When you say "devices" in the first paragraph, do you mean that neither of your computers has a USB-C port?

Comment: USB standards are a [complete mess](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+standards+are+a+mess&oq=usb+standards+are+a+mess&aqs=chrome..69i57.4777j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) right now.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage indeed, neither my laptop nor my desktop have USB-C ports

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the link to the hub on Amazon is now dead. The question is not really useful in this state.

Answer (score 1):

You have purchased a pretty sophisticated "port replicator", which is more like a "docking station", and it has a lot of auxiliary functionality like Power Delivery to charge a laptop "in reverse" (aka "accessory adapter"). This functionality requires full-blown PD communication over Type-C "CC channel", which employs sophisticated serial protocol. The female port (in normal modern laptop) must be able to communicate and respond properly.

To communicate over CC lines and have the Type-C port "flippable", the female receptacle must have serious electronics inside, at least a CC-PD controller, and a super-speed port swap multiplexer. It also must include a port power switch to be compliant with Type-C specifications (no VBUS unless connected), while classic USB ports have VBUS opwer always on.

Your "adapter", however, doesn't look  like having any electronics at all, just a goofy cheap mechanical adapter, with no power switch and no responses to CC commands. That's why it doesn't work with a sophisticated port replicator. Maybe, only maybe some primitive USB devices will work with this dongle, but any serious multi-functional dual-role USB links won't. You need to examine this dongle for functionality and compliance to Type-C specifications, and likely need to get a better Type-A to Type-C converter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I only tried the adapter with a memory card reader and it worked, thus I assume it works in general.

Can you recommend an adapter that would be sufficient in my situation. Also, would it ever work with USB 2.0 port at all?

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out that my initially planned setup doesn't work. I'm not sure why but my guess is that the conversion of USB-C to USB-A renders the hub undetectable for Windows 10.

How a USB-C female receptacle to USB-A male jack adapter is to function is left undefined by the USB specification, that's because they explicitly state these adapters would allow for dangerous cable configurations which may damage USB ports.

> I had concerns whether either the hub or adapter are not functioning properly but after tests with other devices I concluded the problem is with the USB ports on the laptop and desktop.

I have one guess on how those ports could have been damaged.  It's been a while, has this been problem been resolved somehow?

> Do you have any ideas how I can bypass this issue?

I'll need the end goal defined more clearly.  My guess is you are wanting to share a monitor and keyboard with a laptop and desktop.  In that case you need a KVM switch.

> I am thinking as last resort I may have to buy and install PCI Express USB-C adapter card on the desktop

That sounds like a great idea.

> but I am clueless on what to do with the laptop.

I suggest a dock with DisplayLink if you want a dock with video.  DisplayLink is a graphics chip for USB, lots of choices for docks with these chips from lots of different brands.  I would not call a DisplayLink chip a "GPU" exactly as these are rather primitive, don't expect to win frame rate races with these.  They work fine for office productivity and web surfing though.  If you don't need video output then there's plenty of options for USB hubs and docks.

Destroy those USB-C to USB-A adapters before you do more damage with them.